# A weird while loop syntax

Tags: javascript, while-loop

this code: http://ajaxian.com/archives/attack-of-the-ie-conditional-comment

```
var ie = (function(){
    var undef, v = 3, div = document.createElement('div');

    while (
        div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE '+(++v)+']><i></i>< ![endif]-->',
        div.getElementsByTagName('i')[0]
    );

    return v > 4 ? v : undef;
}());
```

Could you please explain to me why this `while` loop works? Is that even correct syntax?


Edit: I do understand what this code is trying to do, but the syntax is just not obvious to me..

Comment: The duplicate isn't just similar, it's actually asking about that exact same snippet of code.

Comment: Wow :D hadn't found the duplicate, have to be honest, that is a really nice catch! Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

It works because the first statement gets executed and due to comma operator, only the second statement is considered for evaluation, which will evaluate to `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

This `while` loop is correct, because in `while` statements are seperated by `,` so the last statement's value will be used as condition of while.

This while loop will finish whenever `div.getElementsByTagName('i')[0]` will be `null` or `undefined`.